# Naming coordinates in a foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, random-numbers

I have the following problem: I am using `beamer` together with `tikz`, and I want to use some random points in a drawing which is shown over a couple of slides.
If I use the normal random method, the points are regenerated after each slides, having different coordinates which I dont want:

```
\foreach \x in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
  \foreach \y in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
    \draw[fill,scale=1] ($ (\x,\ y) + 1/10 * (rand, rand) $)
      \coordinate ( \x\y ) node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt] {};
```

Obviously I need to somehow save the coordinates for later use.
I thought that I could to this using for loops declaring coordinates:

```
\foreach \x in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
  \foreach \y in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
    \coordinate( \x\y ) at ($ (\x,\ y) + 1/10 * (rand, rand) $);
```

This seems to work, but I can't access the coordinates later:

```
\foreach \x in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
  \foreach \y in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
    \draw[fill,scale=1] ( \x\y )
      \coordinate ( \x\y ) node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt] {};
```

This piece of code gives me the error: "No shape named 1/61/6."

I don't know if I am going about this in the right way, I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some errors/quirks in your code: In your first example, you're using the incorrect syntax `\draw ... \coordinate`. You should use `\draw ... coordinate` (note the missing `\` before `coordinate`).

Also, in the first snippet, you're using `\draw` without any drawing commands, instead you're following with `node`. This is technically okay, but you should really either use `\path ... node`, or just a `\draw ... circle` or `\fill ... circle` command. I would suggest you use `\fill ... circle`, since `node` is a bit to powerful if you just need small circles.

Also, there's a spurious space in `\ y`. There also shouldn't be spaces in between the factor and the coordinate in `($ (\x,\y) + 1/10 * (rand, rand) $)`. In general, you have to be careful with spaces: When you name coordinates, the spaces matter: `\coordinate ( A )` is not the same as `\coordinate (A)`. Correcting all this, your first snippet, which draws the circles for the first time and saves their coordinates, could look like this:

```
\foreach \x in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
  \foreach \y in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
    \fill ($ (\x,\y) + 1/10*(rand, rand) $) circle [radius=1pt] coordinate   (\x\y);
```

Then you can draw circles at the same positions later on using

```
\foreach \x in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
  \foreach \y in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
    \fill  (\x\y) circle [radius=1pt];
```

Here's a complete example (it's generally a good idea to post questions using complete examples like this, since it makes finding errors much easier):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{One}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
  \foreach \y in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
    \fill ($ (\x,\y) + 1/10*(rand, rand) $) circle [radius=1pt] coordinate   (\x\y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Two}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
  \foreach \y in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
    \fill  (\x\y) circle [radius=1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, instead of saving the coordinates, you could set the seed for the random number generator by setting `\pgfmathsetseed{<integer>}`. That would have the added benefit that you can try out different values for the seed and find the one that gives the nicest / "most random" pattern, and is reproducible.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{One}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\foreach \x in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
  \foreach \y in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
    \fill ($ (\x,\y) + 1/10*(rand, rand) $) circle [radius=1pt] ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Two}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\foreach \x in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
  \foreach \y in {1/6,3/6,5/6}
    \fill ($ (\x,\y) + 1/10*(rand, rand) $) circle [radius=1pt] ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick help, that does the trick for me. But just out of academic curiousity: Why can't I access the saved coordinates?

Comment: @x2b: Sorry, I was working on a longer answer and pressed `Save` accidentally.